# Fact about PSD matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading something where $C$ is a positive semi-definite matrix. Also, the centring matrix is $H = (I - (1/n)11^{T})$.

My notes say that $C$ is p.s.d. $\implies HCH$ is p.s.d. I'm just not seeing seeing why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A matrix $C$ is called positive semidefinite if $y^\ast Cy\ge0$ for all vector $y$. When $C$ is positive semidefinite, $H^\ast CH$ is positive semidefinite for *every* matrix $H$, because for any vector $x$, if we put $y=Hx$, we get $x^\ast(H^\ast CH)x=(Hx)^\ast C(Hx)=y^\ast Cy\ge0$.

Now your $H$ is real symmetric. Hence $H^\ast=H$ and $HCH=H^\ast CH$. So, the statement in the previous paragraph is applicable.

Comment: Thanks very much - been through this and get it now.